# Cursors in SQL Server: High Performance Penalty

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cursors

**CallTable**

```
CallId |    Date | Time |   MemberID |  CallDuration
12     |    02.02.2015| 13:33:54|   3245|   234 |
13     |    02.02.2015| 13:37:24|   3245|   33  |
```

**ActivityTable**

```
Date*********** Time*** MemberId    ***Activity
02.02.2015***   13:31:22*** 3245*** A
02.02.2015***   13:34:54*** 3245*** B
```

My boss wants to know what **activity** members (employees) were doing (or the the previous activity ) when they received a phone call. This data is stored in two tables given above.

I am using Cursor to get  each row from CallTable and then another cursor within a loop to retrieve the last activity. There are about 1 million rows in the CallTable and it is taking very long to process this.  There is no Primary-Foreign key relationship based on CallID in the CallTable.

Can anyone here please suggest how can I achieve this with JOIN and avoid the use of Cursors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition.

Comment: For SS2008 Gordon's query should be the best. For a different approach you need a Cumulative Sum or Last_Value, both are not supported before SS2012

Comment: OK, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this using a correlated subquery or by using `APPLY`.  For instance:

```
select c.*, a.activity
from calltable c outer apply
     (select top 1 a.*
      from activitytable a
      where a.memberId = c.memberId and
            a.datetime <= c.datetime
      order by a.datetime asc
     ) a;
```

This assumes the date/time is in the same column, which would be the proper way to store this value.  If they are in different columns, similar (but more complex) logic works.

For performance, you want an index on `activitytable(memberid, datetime)`.

Comment: If you have a single column to "extract" from `activitytable`, you can do a subquery instead of an `outer apply`...

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos, can you please let me know how the query and the subquery would look like? I, at the moment, only need to extract a single column from the **activitytable**.

Comment: @dbStudent . . . There is no reason *not* to use `apply`.  However, the subquery approach is basically the same.  Just put the subquery in the `select` clause and change the `a.*` to `a.activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Lag and Lead may be helpful to you

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Here is a Northwind mini example.

```
select * , DaysSincePreviousOrder = datediff(d , PreviousValue, OrderDate)  from (

  SELECT
LAG(p.OrderDate) OVER (ORDER BY p.CustomerID, p.OrderDate) PreviousValue,
p.CustomerID, p.OrderDate,
LEAD(p.OrderDate) OVER (ORDER BY p.CustomerID , p.OrderDate) NextValue
FROM dbo.Orders p where CustomerID = 'anatr' ) as derived1
where derived1.OrderDate = (select max(OrderDate) from dbo.Orders o where o.CustomerID = derived1.CustomerID)

GO
```

99.9% of things can be done without a cursor.  I've written one cursor in 10 years...and haven't revisited it to see if I could refactor.
I think it was a "hit several database" type of thing.  But that's the miniscule exception to the rule...keep pursuing "set based" and non cursor solutions.